# Bijective meets mixed base

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, base-conversion

### Background

A [bijective base \$b\$ numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration), where \$b\$ is a positive integer, is a bijective positional notation that makes use of \$b\$ symbols with associated values of \$1,2,\cdots,b\$.

Bijective base 2 representations of positive integers look like this:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 11
4 -> 12
5 -> 21
6 -> 22
7 -> 111
8 -> 112
9 -> 121
10 -> 122
```

Now, let's apply this to a mixed base. Bijective mixed base \$[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n]\$ numeration uses \$1,\cdots,b_k\$ as the symbols for each digit place, and the digit value of each digit place is \$\prod_{i=k+1}^{n}b_i\$, as in the usual mixed base. This system can uniquely represent the integers from 1 up to the number represented by \$b_1b_2\cdots b_n\$.

Some numbers in bijective base \$[2,3,4]\$:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
4 -> 4
5 -> 11
9 -> 21
16 -> 34
17 -> 111
28 -> 134
29 -> 211
40 -> 234
```

### Challenge

Given the base \$b=[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n]\$ and a positive integer \$x\$, convert \$x\$ to bijective mixed base \$b\$ as a list of digit values. It is guaranteed that \$x\$ is representable in the system. Some digits of \$b\$ may be greater than 9. You can take the input \$b\$ and give output in either most- or least-significant-digit-first order (mixing is also OK).

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

<sup>Protip: Jelly does not have this built-in.</sup>

### Test cases

Test cases are written in most-significant-digit-first order.

```
x = 1, b = [1] -> [1]
x = 3, b = [1,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1]

For b = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
x = 1 -> [1]
x = 4 -> [4]
x = 10 -> [2, 2]
x = 20 -> [1, 1, 4]
x = 35 -> [2, 2, 3]
x = 56 -> [1, 2, 1, 4]
x = 84 -> [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
x = 112 -> [2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for b = [8, 9, 10, 11]:
x = 1 -> [1]
x = 2 -> [2]
x = 6 -> [6]
x = 24 -> [2, 2]
x = 120 -> [10, 10]
x = 720 -> [6, 5, 5]
x = 5040 -> [4, 9, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
x=>b=>b.flatMap(v=>x?x-(x=~-x/v|0)*v:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDBDoIwDAbgu0@x42YGbmMgaoZP4BMQDlPBaAgQIcsOxlefjngxWUKTnpqvTfs/tNHj5Xkfpqjrr7VrlLOqOH8rblo9nfSAjSrs0UbYqndkN@bFyNrsy4q4S9@NfVvHbX/DDeYEl7wi5LD67ye@T9GvAsAPSooSisRsRMBIgOEMgAQEJSkApRkA5aDDuYAon6OPkFG0oygPPbdMMsAWuWz4nOMC2kJQymRIuQ8)

Comment: Or [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##ldDfCoIwFAbw@56iyy3S9k@zYvYEPYF4sUyjkE1Sxq569TU0iMDgBPt2c34bnO@urOqrx60bIm0utW@kdzI/hxM3rRpOqkNW5u7oIuTkM3Ibi1d2X5TYV0b3pq3j1lxRg6jGqKC6xPiw@J7wabJefjKjxvciTHkIe0s2JwVYUgKmDE55AqZJCqbZH2tRBrdj@WPrJFy7kGx2f6BLof8JIKRT8wC5BcuEiJ/UvwA) with BigInts.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

Based on [@tsh's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236995/9288).

-6 bytes thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Map[x=#;Pick[x-(x=⌊--x/#⌋)#,x>=0]&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BCoMwEEX3nmIgIC0kVGO0lhLxAgX3IYsgLZViKcVFQLxA6ym9iDXS4qIOzGze@zDza9Ncz7VpqtKMF5DjyTyUleRYVOVNWbaxcuhfjNkdGfr3llCbyUD72h@LZ3VvVEtIByyDiyJaEa41@JDnuQdtG1Jw66brqAfQRgtZoIsJCpPjM@dfLhAeBojgmIhiRMQJIlL0eMgx47q5WtMXBwrp76l1nCBpsc7DuduK2GMiDsS/6cYP)

Inputs and outputs are in least-significant-digit-first order.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY9BCoMwEEX3nmIgIC0kVGO0lhLxAgX3IYsgLZViKcVFQLxA6ym9iDXS4qIOzGze@zDza9Ncz7VpqtKMF5DjyTyUleRYVOVNWbaxcuhfjNkdGfr3llCbyUD72h@LZ3VvVEtIByyDiyJaEa41@JDnuQdtG1Jw66brqAfQRgtZoIsJCpPjM@dfLhAeBojgmIhiRMQJIlL0eMgx47q5WtMXBwrp76l1nCBpsc7DuduK2GMiDsS/6cYP) inputting `[x][b]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
0#_=[]
a#(b:c)|q<-div(a-1)b=a-b*q:q#c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc/BCoJAEAbgu08xsB00VtjZXc0kn0QkdjVoySwrOvXumxiERiNz@78ZmP9o7qdD23ov2L4oq8Cw0OZ19Op3ceOeoYkxsoWJ7brPe1b7s3EdFNBcAoDrzXUPWAECgxL5MNUkVd90no/bmisuB5FT0aSgIEnSpBKSkpSkbOENlLSNdYeugm95NvuQlJS@0SThp/Ff2yxYIvQP@jc)

Inputs and outputs are in least-significant-digit-first order.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->x,b{b.map{|y|x>0&&x-y*x= ~-x/y}-[!0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdC9CoMwFAXgvU9xuziUxCZRW0uILyIZGtCtIJaWBLWvnqaCq6eE/AxfuIczvlyIvYm88cxNLn/ch2kOs29ElnkeTt7Qh/tzWHh7FHaJngxJTS5drbSkaaC@TV/zsXt347Oz2@Pwk8Um2bp2/QoVI8konQWj0up1GhpSIiAFEgqKokKiuiBR46RSwYpqRrfUkkhb/tmQQgBGVzg67vCKSSXKPRO/)

Freely adapted from tsh's Javascript

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,l:n*l and[~-n%l[0]+1]+f(~-n//l[0],l[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDbboQgFHzfryAkzcIuuoBorcb9EeVBdzW1oWi2PtiX/rpFwMa0jZfDzJkzZ8L4Ob0OOlqWrlD1e3OvgSYq0ycFan0vvwL9pEoqz0yeO2TQ5bJCokqWSby0c3tDsNLjo9cT6tBMmjLLAiaxK@QvVRQDrjQM34ZeIwjhDArActCYUjIJgutaDisbbSyxj@/Z48E2OAGMAPOPCBAyt057A2GBcIBRi4yaO4JTb7iaeFEU/4iMq@PiZNPxvTQVu3E3sG1ifHPZxXORUwJeDE3Nx/5J7AcdcHsT3xG/4rMt/@pFHffsuYSA2Lw@PxWOFXZ3ah3MxYePdlT1rUUwuEIC88FoIQ4/RtVP6FjpI8Z4@QY)

reversed digit order

Comment: You can save a byte by switching to Python 2 and using `/` instead of `//`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`(1+),*;(\1)*(1+)
;$#2$*1,$.3
.*;,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY27DoMwDEV3/wYZwLFQ7CQ85F9hAIkOXTpU/f80sMTIg@85kn2/r9/7c5SynR4cgt979gOh9hsPeGVQ14lDJjdGGFEJSmFlYLpHI0jdQpFStS0n64MBsRCzgTwZWB4PWGChlTgQX@UtWz9Zn@xB7Ww0PyiHFP4) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the order `b₁,...,bₙ;x`. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`(1+),*;(\1)*(1+)
;$#2$*1,$.3
```

Repeatedly divmod `x` by `b` in reverse order, but always ensuring that the remainder is non-zero, and convert the remainder to decimal, but keep the quotient in unary.

```
.*;,
```

Delete any unused bases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｗ∧θ⊟η«≦⊖θ←⸿Ｉ⊕﹪θι≧÷ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxPC4IwGMfxc76KB0/PYIFCQX9OkpcgQbqah@GWG6xN57JD9NqXEtjt4eH7@zSSucYyHcJLKi0AM8Oxp1DaDiUhBN7RqmBdNgyqNZiLxomHMF5wCj05RqvSKePxcBF3TyG@ufj/PLHB49ksCywsf2o762qS53CRr6qVc@xzNSoupuLnf0KotskmoVDtKOwppNOZpnUd1qP@Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is in left-to-right order. Explanation:

```
Ｗ∧θ⊟η«
```

While `x` is nonzero, retrieve the previous mixed base `b` from the list of mixed bases.

```
≦⊖θ
```

Decrement `x`.

```
←⸿Ｉ⊕﹪θι
```

Reduce `x` modulo `b`, then increment the result, and print it on the previous line.

```
≧÷ιθ
```

Integer divide `x` by `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 79 bytes

```
func[n b][r: copy[]until[insert r(n: n - 1)%(t: take/last b)+ 1 1 > n: n / t]r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7NCsJADITv@xRDQVBE7K6tPwV9CK8hh/5ssVi3ZV2hPn1NC168mZDDDMOX8bYar7YiVqrOMNYvV5JDweQzlF3/Jn650LTUuKf1AX7pMjhsoFeLZcgQ8rvdtvkzoFitoWUvmBNbBPY89r4rLGrxSbP6qp2oOaynt523eXnDMJkJdAwTY5ci3eMoUhsGKcj0vnEBFA04R5KONpcIj66tBDjMXQEyAjXCT5jVL9tgDyNEwR/k0jiJ/0EfcZrKaT2hxw8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
vD_#<y‰`>,
```

Inputs are in the order \$[b],x\$. I/O are both in least-significant-digit-first order, so reversed of the challenge description. The output is newline delimited.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/zCVe2abyUcOGBDud//@jTXSMdYx0DHWMYrmMDAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5epUJvwvc4lXtql81LAhwU7nf@2hbfb/o6MNdaINY2N1FKKNgQwdMARzgeImOsY6RkABI7CACbqAoQG6iBGGiLEpuoipGbqIBabJhkYYQkDXAZ1moGOpYwGxC13ADEOFCbqIIciBqELmmEKmBiaoYrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
v           # Loop `y` over the first (implicit) input-list:
 D          #  Duplicate the current integer
            #  (which is the second implicit input-integer in the first iteration,
            #  and the quotient of the divmod every other iteration)
  _         #  If this is 0:
   #        #   Stop the loop
    <       #  (Else) Decrease the integer by 1
     y‰     #  Divmod it by `y`
       `    #  Pop and push both values separated to the stack
        >   #  Increase the top (the remainder) by 1
         ,  #  Pop and output it with trailing newline
```